# how to write a script which will displays only regulars files

Tags: scripts

Someone can say me how to Writing a script,which will displays the number of regular files in the current folder and each of its subfolders ?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking for a **count** of regular files or a **list**?

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment - what have you tried?

Comment: @steeldriver 
#!/bin/bash
ls /B-CPE-100-COT-1-1-cpoolday02-sidney.yeto | wc -l
But I have the irregular files too in results

Comment: @DaveWhite I ask indeed a count of regular files

Answer (score 1):

To get a count of all the regular files in the current directory and its subfolders, you can use

```
find . -type f -printf x | wc -c
```

Note that "regular files" include hidden files (aka "dotfiles") which you will not see with plain `ls` (it would need `ls -A` or `ls -a`)

Comment: I just want to get a count for regular files in directory and its subfolders

Answer (score 0):

`find . -type f -name "[^.]*" | wc -l`

Find (`find`) all files in current directory (`.`) (includes subdirectories) of type "file" (`-type f`), match all filenames that do not start with a dot (`-name "[^.]*"`, that is a regular expression), pipe `|` output to `wc` and count the lines (`-l`)

Comment: Piping to filenames to `wc -l` has the disadvantage that it will miscount files whose names include a newline (rare but legal in *nix filesystems). Also `[^.]*` in this context is a glob (shell metacharacter) expression, rather than a regular expression (in any case, hidden files **are** regular files in the usual definition of "regular").

Comment: I see, thank you for pointing that out. I guess newlines in filenames really are edge cases, but your point is legit. So, combining my solution with yours, I'd go with a `find . -type f -name "[^.]*" -printf x | wc -c` - due to the `-name` it will skip all files starting with a dot, which I think is what the op wants.

Comment: Yes that may well be the case - I guess we need the OP to confirm